# how find permutation Group power 23 without multiplicative it 23 time?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

${ if \  \sigma = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\ 4&2&5&3&1 \end{pmatrix} , \ \tau = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\ 3&5&4&2&1 \end{pmatrix} 
 }$

${ Find: (i) O( \sigma\tau) \ \ , \ \ (ii) (\sigma\tau)^{23} }$

i found order ${ O( \sigma\tau)\ }$ = 4
 and i don't know law  give me 
(ii) without multiplication ${( \sigma\tau) }$ 23 time ?

Comment: Well since the order of $\sigma\tau$ is $4$, $(\sigma\tau)^{23}\cdot\sigma\tau=1$. So, the answer is simply $\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order of $(\sigma \tau)$ is $4$, then we know that $(\sigma \tau)^4 = e$. Then $(\sigma \tau)^{4k} = e$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Then $e = (\sigma \tau)^{24} = (\sigma \tau)^{23} \cdot (\sigma \tau)$. Hence, $(\sigma \tau)^{23} = (\sigma \tau)^{-1}$